# Who is the Devata for diseases?

Tags: gods

Every natural phenomenon has a presiding Devata that is responsible for it. Agni for fire, Vayu for wind, Varuna for water, Bhudevi for Earth, Dyaus Pita for akasha, Indra for storms and lightning, Yama for death, and so on.

Is there any Devata that is responsible for propagating diseases and illnesses through microbial agents?

Comment: Ashwinikumars are deities of healing but deity who cause decease is yama himself. his punishment causes person to become sick.but in general any deity can give punishments. Krishna cursed his own son in mahabharata.

Comment: Nirṛti  may be, when in home have these piegeon nest, cat or dog. then it invites nirrti to be present in that home

Comment: Nothing like that,  people use some ayurvedic trees to cure the disease.